# Get Data from GridView into DataTable in C# WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, datatable

I am working on a webapp that currently has a GridView binded to MSSQL. The GridView correctly displays the data from the database, and I have made one of the columns to be displayed in a textbox.

What I am trying to do is, to get the changes that the user made to the data on the GridView, so that I can update the SQL Database. I want to get the new(changed) data from the GridView into a DataTable, so that I can compare it to the Original DataTable. However when I try to insert the data from the GridView into a new DataTable, I keep getting blanks into the cells.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtU = new DataTable();

        if (GridView.HeaderRow != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dtU.Columns.Add(GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
            }
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtU.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
            }
            dtU.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        DataTable dtOrigData = GlobalVariables.dsOrigData.Tables[0];

        //Get changes
        var rowsTest = dtOrigData.AsEnumerable().Where(
            r => !dtU.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Name"]).ToList().Contains(r["Name"])).ToList();

    //do some code to update the SQL Database with the changes
    }
```

PS. Is there another easier way to update the Database?

Comment: is your "GridView" a DataGridView? why don't you just bind your DataTable to GridView.DataSource and use a SqlDataAdapter to write your changes to the server?

Comment: Because when I bind the DataTable to the GridView.DataSource, I get the original data back, and not the data with the changes that the user made.

Comment: that should not be the case if you create a correct UpdateCommand for your SqlDataAdapter ...

Comment: I cant get to that point, because if I bind the DataTable to the GridView.DataSource, I get the same exact DataTable as the original one, with no changes. Once I know my program is getting the changes, then I can use the UpdateCommand to update the DB.

Comment: Also, No it is not a DataGridView, as it is a WebApp.